# Melhor maneira de adicionar vários ítens de um pedido em uma tabela

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Quando adiciono um pedido na tabela `TB_PEDIDOS`,

```
TB_PEDIDOS:
ID_PEDIDO, DATA_PEDIDO, ID_CLIENTE
```

Também preciso adicionar os detalhes do pedido em uma outra tabela:

```
TB_DETALHES_PEDIDOS:
ID_PEDIDO, ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, PRECO
```

Exemplo:

```
Produto1 QTD:2 PRECO:5
Produto2 QTD:1 PRECO:2
Produto3 QTD:8 PRECO:3
```

Adiciono os detalhes com um loop, ou existe outra maneira de fazer isso?

O banco é SQL SERVER.

Comment: por favor, melhore a questão !!!

Comment: ve se da pra entender agora..

Comment: @Gerson, sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, mais pelo que entendi você quer saber se existe alguma maneira de inserir dados em 2 tabelas no mesmo `insert`, para adicionar o pedido e os items em um único `insert`? É isso? Algo como um `insert` em `cascade`?

Comment: vc esta usando algum Framework ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Table Value Constructor, para SQL-Server 2008 ou superior

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

```
INSERT INTO TB_PEDIDOS (QTD, PRECO, ...)
  SELECT QTD, PRECO--, ...
    FROM ( VALUES (2, 5)
                , (1, 2)
                , (8, 3)         
         ) tPedidos (QTD, PRECO)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT TB_DETALHES_PEDIDOS (ID_PEDIDO, ID_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, PRECO)
SELECT pe.ID_PEDIDO, pd.ID_PRODUTO, RAND() * 100, RAND() * 1000
FROM TB_PEDIDO pe
CROSS JOIN TB_PRODUTO pd
```

`RAND()` gera um número entre 0 e 1. Coloquei 100 para produto e 1000 para preço apenas como exemplos (coloca de 0 a 100 produtos e de 0 a 1000 preços diferentes).